# Where are the figures for this WIPO application?

Tags: google-patents, wo2014078355a1

Regarding the patent: [WO2014078355a1](https://patents.google.com/patent/WO2014078355A1/en)

Where are the figures referred to in the patent? I can't find them on the patent page.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140136171A1/en for the corresponding US application, and
- http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?CC=WO&NR=2014078355A1&KC=A1&FT=D&ND=&date=20140522&DB=&&locale=en_EP, from which you can download all 55 pages.